# Is it possible to properly memoize reselect selectors when using denormalize?

Tags: reactjs, redux, memoization, reselect, normalizr

I recently noticed that when using normalizr’s ‘denormalize’ function within a reselect selector, memoization was failing every time.

This is down to having to pass the entire entities object to the selector as an argument, which i suppose is too deeply nested for the shallow comparison.

Does anyone have any ideas for how you could go about preserving memoization here, or would trying to memoize entities be an over optimisation?

Thanks!